# jquery Cycle disable the slideshow via callback

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

Is there any way I can use the 'before' callback to disable the slideshow? The slideshow works 'manually' with the nex / prev options so I'd like to disable those. I tried removing the id attribute but that doesn't disable the button.

Maybe the forwardFlag option can be used for this?

```
$('#slider-form').cycle({
        fx:     'fade', 
        speed:  'fast',
        prev:   '#prev', 
        next:   '#next', 
        width:  940,
        fit: 1,
        before: onBefore,
        after: onAfter,
        nowrap: 1,
        timeout: 0      
    });

function onBefore(currSlideElement, nextSlideElement, options, forwardFlag) {
    //condition is not met: disable next/prev animation

    //condition is met: enable navigation
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Pause and resume options.

```
$('#slider-form').cycle('pause'); 

$('#slider-form').cycle('resume');
```

Check this [example](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/pause.html).

**Update**

You can try this different way.

Remove the default next/prev options.
Create your own button.

On the click of that button use the next/prev function.

For example.

```
$("#my_next_button").click(function(){

 condition {

        $('#slider-form').cycle('next');
 }

});
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, probably causing I'm manually triggering the prev/next slide.

Comment: This works but not immediately. When I click 'next' and the condition is false I want to be able to cancel the upcoming action: showing the next slide. Removing the event handler will cancel the action the next time the link is clicked but not cancel the 'current' action. Close!